# R OR comparing two booleans, I want F | NA to return F

Tags: r

I have a situation where I have two vectors with 1's, 0's and NA's. I want to take the highest non-NA value at each index.

Eg. take these two vectors v1 and v2:

```
v1 = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,NA,NA,0,1)
v2 = c(1,NA,1,0,1,NA,1,NA,0,1)
```

You could convert them to boolean and do `v1 | v2` but then there is the following problem:

```
1 | 0 = T
0 | 1 = T
1 | 1 = T
0 | 0 = F
NA | NA = NA <--- Good
1 | NA = T <-- Good
0 | NA = NA <--- I want this to return F
```

There's another solution using `apply` and `max`, but the problem is that `max(c(NA,NA), na.rm=T)` returns `-Inf`.

Any way to do this in a one liner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're comparing two numeric vectors it doesn't make sense to me to convert them to logical vectors to determine the pairwise largest values. `pmax` returns the element-wise maximum of vectors and comes with a `na.rm` option to handle missing values:

```
pmax(v1, v2, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1]  1  0  1  0  1  1  1 NA  0  1
```